# Angular/Aggrid: Proper way to turn this GET request function into a service?

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient, ag-grid

I am loading data form a json-server to the datagrid, Ag grid. Now I can display the data fine in the grid, and I set up an interval function that makes a get request every 5 seconds and displays any updated data to the grid. This all works fine. Now this works fine for some data I have, as this specific data will constantly be changed/updated by the server, not the users.

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

rowData: any[];
columnDefs: any

constructor(...) {
this.columnDefs =[
{headerName: "data", field: "data"}
]
}
ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getData('http://localhost:3000/employees')
      this.refreshData();
      this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
          this.refreshData(); 
        }, 5000);
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }

      refreshData(){
        this.service.getData('http://localhost:3000/employees')
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.rowData = data;            
             })
      }
```

But I have a form where a user can enter in their own data, and save it to the server. I would like for my form component to use **refreshData()** so that it does not have to wait x amount of seconds to post to the grid. Here is the saveUser function:

```
saveUser() {
       this.employeeInfo = this.frmUser.getRawValue();
       var url = 'http://localhost:3000/employees';
       this.http.post(url, this.employeeInfo, httpOptions)
         .subscribe((res: any) => {
           this.service.refreshData(//unsure what to pass here)
            //unsure how to pass the data to the rowData from the TableComponent 
            //res = ?
           this.dialogRef.close({
             success: "success"
           });
         });
     }
```

Calling my getData service does not update the table. **This is because I am unsure how to pass data to rowData since I am working in FormComponent. RowData is initalized in TableComponent**

I tried making a service, but rowData is still not updated. When running the code, nothing new happens.

```
//service       
getData(url: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(url).pipe(
        map(this.extractData),
        catchError(this.handleErrorObservable));

    }
      private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res;
        console.log(res)
        return body || {};
      }

    refreshData(data) {
      this.getData(this._url) 
      .subscribe(result => {
       data = result
       console.log(data)
      });
    }
```

**Question: How can I properly turn refreshData into a service so that I can use it in my Form Component class?** It seems all I am missing is a way to transfer data to rowData Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saveUser() should be a service that is called from a function in your component, i named it onSave(). That function will subscribe to the service and then handle the success of the request in the component.

Edit: if you are looking to have these in 2 separate components, and you want to force the table to update after you add a new value to the table you are going to want to use something like an [EventEmitter](https://netbasal.com/event-emitters-in-angular-13e84ee8d28c).

```
//example.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.refreshData();
  this.interval = setInterval(() => { 
      this.refreshData(); 
    }, 5000);
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}

refreshData() {
    this.service.getEmployeeData()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.rowData = data;            
        });
}

// Called when the user clicks save on the form
onSave() {
    const newUser = this.formUser.getRawValue();
    this.service.saveUser(newUser)
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.refreshData()
            this.dialogRef.close({
                success: "success"
            });
        })
}
```

---

```
//example.service.ts
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/employees';
saveUser(employeeInfo: any): Observable<any> {
   //adds an entry to employee data
   return this.http.post(url, this.employeeInfo, httpOptions)
}

getEmployeeData(): Observable<any> {
    //retrieves all the employee data entries
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
        map(res => res || {}),
        catchError(this.handleErrorObservable)
    );
}
```

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Event Emitter seems like the right route. Now I am guessing I would need to use the event emitter in the form component class? (where the onSave method is). So that when the button is clicked, the event emitter triggers the refreshData function from my table component class.

Comment: Yeah, you would want to declare the EventEmitter in the form component and call emit() when you save. Then subscribe to that EventEmitter in your table component and everytime you see an emit called refresh the table, the link in my answer shows a pretty good example of how this would be done